# Matrix possibilities in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, matrix, statistics, reduce

**Hello**

As you can see in my gist below, I have 03 different properties in an object or array (I could use any one of this as input), and I have to discover all the possibilities of combination between them.

In this case, we just have 03 properties, but we can easily have more than 20 props ...

How could I implement this in a smart way? Thinking about a bigger amount of data ...

https://gist.github.com/matheus-rossi/c0261d1d8e138475c049f500fb2616fa

```
const configPossibilities = [ [ 1 ], [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] ] 

const configPossibilities2 = {
 ID_LINHA: [ 1 ],
 ID_IMPLEMENTO: [ 1 , 2 ],
 ID_COMPOSICAO: [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ]
} 

const desiredResult = [
  [1, 1, 1 ],
  [1, 1, 2 ],
  [1, 1, 3 ],
  [1, 1, 4 ],
  [1, 2, 1 ],
  [1, 2, 2 ],
  [1, 2, 3 ],
  [1, 1, 4 ],
]
```

Comment: use json maybe? not really sure what you mean by 'smart way'

Comment: i need to calculate all possibilities having that arrays as params, i can't mount it manually in a JSON, because my real case have more then 20 possibilities

Answer (score 0):

```
  function getPossibilities(obj){
    return cartesian(...Object.values(obj))
  }

  function cartesian() {
    var r = [], arg = arguments, max = arg.length-1
    function helper(arr, i) {
      for (var j=0, l=arg[i].length; j<l; j++) {
        var a = arr.slice(0)
        a.push(arg[i][j])
        if (i==max) {
          r.push(a)
        }
        else {
          helper(a, i+1)
        }
      }
    }
    helper([], 0)
    return r
  }

  const desiredResult = getPossibilities(configPossibilities2)
```